# Add existing Service account to terraform Google compute instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-compute-engine, terraform-provider-gcp

Hello I am trying to add an existing service account to a new Google compute instance I am spinning up.

How can I attach the already existing account?

Here is what my file looks like

```
provider "google" {
project = var.project
region = "us-central1"
zone = "us-central1-c"
}

resource "google_compute_disk" "data_disk" {
    name = "data-test"
    size = 120
}

resource "google_compute_disk" "other_data_disk" {
    name = "other-data-test"
    size = 400
}

resource "google_compute_attached_disk" "data" {
    disk = google_compute_disk.data_disk.id
    instance = google_compute_instance.test_vm_instance.id
}

resource "google_compute_attached_disk" "other_data" {
    disk = google_compute_disk.other_data_disk.id
    instance = google_compute_instance.tyler_test_vm_instance.id
}

resource "google_compute_instance" "test_vm" {
    name = "worker-test"
    machine_type = "n2-standard-2"
    min_cpu_platform = "Intel Ice Lake"
    


    
    boot_disk {
        initialize_params {
            image = "ubuntu-2004-focal-v20210211"
        }
    }

    network_interface {
        network = var.gcp_project_network_name
        subnetwork = var.subnet_name
        #access_config {
        #}
    }
    metadata_startup_script = "${file("./startup-script.sh")}"
```

What's the best way to insert add an already existing service account to the new VM.
I want to be able to create and destroy the VM without worrying about deleting this service account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to this resource:

```
resource "google_compute_instance" "test_vm" {
...
  service_account {
    email  = REPLACE_WITH_EXISTING_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL_ADDRESS
    scopes = ["cloud-platform"]
  }
...
}
```

Comment: is it possible to update the service account using a different terraform module?

Comment: @PANDAMAN - Please post a new question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/74134361/3260188