# Is it possible to update existing compute engine using terraform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, devops

I'm a beginner in terraform and I'm planning to create a terraform module that updates the tags and service account of an existing compute engine in google cloud.

The problem is this existing VMs were provisioned manually and there is a need to update the tags and service account occasionally.

So far, I created a small module that use `data` to fetch the details and `resource` to create my changes but this doesn't fit the requirement as its creating a new resource.

```
data "google_compute_instance" "data_host" {
  name              = var.instance_name
  project           = var.project_name
  zone              = var.project_zone
}

resource "google_compute_instance" "host" {
  name              = data.google_compute_instance.data_host.self_link
  zone              = data.google_compute_instance.data_host.self_link
  machine_type      = data.google_compute_instance.data_host.self_link 
  boot_disk {
    source          = data.google_compute_instance.data_host.self_link
  }
  network_interface {
    network         = data.google_compute_instance.data_host.self_link
  }
  service_account {
    email           = var.service_account
    scopes          = ["cloud-platform"]
  }
  etc...
}
```

are there anyway to update my existing VMs without recreating the entire system?

Comment: Start here: https://www.terraform.io/cli/commands/import

Comment: Step 1 as John pointed out, import your current GCP state into terraform. Then execute terraform plan and the comparison between the desired state and the current one will ask to recreate or just update.